# How get the language of browser in selenium ide?

Tags: selenium-ide

I am trying to assert if the language of a site matches the user language of the browser.
For web-driver, I think this can be done by getting the `window.navigator.language` and comparing it against the UI.
But how do I get the language of the browser in the IDE?

Answer (score 0):

You can run JavaScript snippets using **execute script**.

For example: `execute script | return window.navigator.language | browserLanguage`